# What collision detection method to use with hand drawn surface?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

I have a lunar lander type game. I don't use any physics engines.
My lander keeps falling if you do not use thruster and eventually lands on the ground. Ground is hand drawn, it is not a line, more like curve, and the land can be of any configuration or color. 
How do I properly use collision detection and its results?

Comment: An important point should be made clear: Does your game allow landing on slightly curved surface (such that the ship slightly tilts to align with the surface upon landing)? Or should the surface be perfectly flat for the landing to be successful?

Comment: @Mazyod Landing pods will be perfectly flat yes

Comment: Oh, this explains a lot then. Let me give it a shot... But, just to make sure, how are you representing the hand drawn line in the code? Is it a series of points connect with lines as I suspect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it depends on what you want to do. I would recommend one of the following:

1. Use physics engines. They are there for something. You could create different shapes what was drawn. You could mix in a rectangle if theres a straight line, or a lot of circles for curves, etc.
2. Use your own custom circle collision detector. You represent the lander with a bounding box sized circle. Then, for each of the handdrawn lines, create a bunch of adjacent circles representing the line. When you check your lander position, you are just basically looping through the circles representing the lines and checking for collisions. Incoming pseudocode

   ```
   for (CollisionCircle* circle in collisions)
   {
       if (circle.collidesWith(lander.collisionCircle))
       {
           // 1. Calculate edge distance from lander to circle (position + radius distance)
           // 2. Remove distance from lander position to fix position.
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: (+1) for physics engines. However, I think the circles idea needs more work. what is the optimal radius of the circle? What about sharp edges?

Comment: true. I workedf on a drawiing app for windows once, and it really depends on the brush you used. If you had sharp edges, it was normally a square brush. The size is likewise dependent on the size brush.

Comment: What do i take as center of circle?

Comment: The center of the line you have. say you have a line drawn perfectly horizontal (y = 0). The circles would be x^2 + y^2 = 1, (x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 0; and so one, aligned on the line, as Andres said