# How does a non-tile based map works?

Tags: dictionary, sdl, render, tile

Ok, here is the thing. Recently i decided i wanted to understand how Random map generation works. I found some papers and some arguments. The most interesting one was "Diamond Square algorithm" and "Midpoint Displacement". I still have to try to apply those to a software, but other than that, i ran into this site: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/

As you can see, the idea is to use polygons. But i have no idea how to apply that a Tile-Based map, not even how to create those polygons using the tools i have (c++ and sdl). I am assuming there is no way to do it ( please correct me if i am wrong.) But if i am not, how does a non-tile map works, and how are these polygons generated?

Comment: Triangles! <http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/2d-non-tile-based-map-editor> |
<https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/1tpmmr/trying_to_create_a_world_for_a_2d_game_that_is/> |
simply 2D triangle based scenario <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK0IKeAoGDU> | <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782211/what-collision-detection-method-to-use-with-hand-drawn-surface/11818299>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer will not give you directly the answers you're looking for, but hopefully will get you close enough!

**The Problem**

I think what blocks you is how to represent the data.  You're probably used to a 2D grid that simply represent the type of each tile.  As you know, this is fine to handle a tile-based map, but doesn't properly allow you to model worlds where tiles are of a different shape.

**Graphs**

What I suggest to you, is to see the problem a bit differently.  A grid is nothing more than a graph ([more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29)) with nodes that have 4 (or 8 if you allow diagonals) implicit neighbor nodes.  So first, what I would do if I was you, would be to move from your strict standard 2D grid to a more "loose" graph, where each node has a `position`, a `position`, a list of `neighbors` (in most cases you'll have corners with 2 neighbors, borders with 3 and "middle" tiles with 4) and finally a `rendering component` which simply draws your tile on screen at the given `position`.  Once this is done, you should be able to have the *exact same* results on screen that you currently have with your "2D Tile-Based" engine by simply calling the `rendering component` with each `node` who's bounding box (didn't touch it in what you should add to your node, but I'll get back to this later) intersects with the camera's frustum (in a 2D world, it would most likely if the position +/- the size intersects the `RECT` currently being drawn).

**Search**

The more generic approach will also help you doing stuff like pathfinding with generic algorithms that explore `nodes` until they find a valid path (see [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) or [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)). Even if you decided to stick to a good old 2D Tile Map game, these techniques would *still* be useful!

**Yeah but I want Polygons**

I hear you!  So, if you want polygons, basically all you need to do, is add to your `nodes` a list of vertices and the appropriate data that you might need to render your polygons (either vertex color, textures and U/V maps, etc...) and update your `rendering component` to do the appropriate `OpenGL` ([this](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html) for example should help) calls to draw your nodes.  Once again, the first step to iteratively upgrade your 2D Tile Engine to a polygon map engine would be to, for each tile in your map, give each of your `nodes` two triangles, a texture resource (the tile), and U/V mappings (0,0 - 0,1 - 1,0 and 1,1).  Once again, when this step is done, you should have a "generic" polygon based tile map engine.  The creation of most of this data can be created procedurally by calculating coordinates based on tile position, tile size, etc...

**Convex Polygons**

If you decide that you ever might need NPCs to navigate on your map or want to allow your player to navigate by clicking the map, I would suggest that you always use [*convex* polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons) (the triangle being the simplest for of a convex polygon).  This allows your code that assume that two different positions on the same polygon can be navigated to in straight line.

**Complex Maps**

Based on the link you provided, you want to have rather complex maps.  In this case, the author used [Voronoi Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) to generate the polygons of the map.  There are already solutions to do triangulation like that, but you might also want to use other techniques that are easier to work with if you're just switching to 3D like [this one for example](http://paulboxley.com/blog/2011/03/terrain-generation-mark-one). Once you have interesting results, you should consider implementing `serialization` to save/open your map data from the game.  If you want to create an editor, be aware that it might be a lot of work but can be worth it if you want people to help you creating maps or to add elements to the maps (like geometry that's not part of the terrain).

I went all over the place with this answer, but hopefully it helps!

Comment: Thank you! This Really helps... I was totally lost for a minute there... This is a lot more complex than what i thought, but nothing that time and hard work cant accomplish :)

Comment: Exactly, break up the problem in simpler steps, and go gradually, this way you'll "always" have something working on your way to a complex system

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over all the tiles, and do a hit-test from the centre of the tile to the polys. Turn the type of the tile into the type of the polygon. Did you need more than that?

EDIT: Sorry, I realize that probably isn't helpful. Playing with procedural algorithms can be fun and profitable. Start with a loop that iterates over all tiles and chooses randomly whether or not the tile is occupied. Then, iterate over them again and choose whether it is occupied or its neighbour is.

Also, check out the source code for this: http://dustinfreeman.org/toys/wall7-dustin.html